# Non-associative Clifford algebra

Tags: reference-request, spin-geometry, clifford-algebras, non-associative-algebras, spinor

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ vector space equipped with a symmetric, bilinear form $b : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$.
My question is if there exists an analog of a Clifford algebra in the context of non-associative $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.

This means the following:
Does there exists a unital, non-commutative, non-associative (i.e. not nessecarily commutative or associative) $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $(Cl_{na}, \iota : V \to Cl_{na})$, where $\iota$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map, s.t. for all unital, non-associative $\mathbb{R}$-algebras $A$ with $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\varphi : V \to A$ which satisfies

$$ 
  \varphi(v) \cdot_A \varphi(w) + \varphi(w) \cdot_A \varphi(v) = -2 b(v,w) \cdot 1_A
$$
for all $v,w \in V$ , there exists a unique map $\tilde{\varphi} : Cl_{na} \to A$, s.t. $\tilde{\varphi} \circ \iota = \varphi$.

If this non-associative algebra exists, is it finite-dimensional?
Can we prove $Cl_{na}(\mathbb{R}^3,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\text{standard}}) \cong \mathbb{O}$, where $\mathbb{O}$ are the octinions.

Comment: You can always start with the free (non-commutative, non-associative) algebra over $V$ and quotient by (the ideal generated by) the relations you want. (The existence of the free algebra itself follows by taking a basis $B$ of $V$ and considering the vector space with basis all fully parenthesized words on $B$.) I doubt this is finite dimensional though: considering the zero bilinear form might be a good start toward testing this.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, this is same what I thought. The questions if we have to strengthen the condition on non-associativity and impose flexible or alternative.

Comment: A better question is: What's a presentation of the Octonions by generators and relations (in the category of non-associative $\mathbb R$-algebras). We want 3 generators $e_1, e_2, e_3$ that square to $-1$, and such that any two of them satisfy the Quaternion algebra relations $(e_ie_j)^2=-1$. Is that a complete set of relations? -- Probably not...

Comment: I think one would at least need to require $e_1 (e_2 e_3) = - (e_1 e_2) e_3$.